# How to send a copy of all the output produced by a script to a file in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I meant to run a long **Powershell** script on Azure CLI which will produce some outputs. My requirement is that I need those outputs on terminals as well as in a file, Is this achievable?

In Azure Shell, the history of terminal output is not great. You can not scroll up to the point you started.

I need to have a proof of the output.
Please suggest.

Comment: Sounds like [Tee-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.3) is what you want.

Comment: You could try -verbose, if your command supports. Then Add-content of verbose output to a file.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, Tee-Object is what i used.

Answer (score 1):

*Generally*, if you want to create a *transcript* of a PowerShell session, use the [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Host/Start-Transcript) and [`Stop-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Host/Stop-Transcript) cmdlets.

- In *interactive* sessions, the transcript will include the *input commands* submitted by the user.
- *Inside a script*, only the script's *output* is recorded.
- Either way, *output* from *all* of PowerShell's [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams):

  - is recorded in the output file.
  - while *also* printing to the *host* (display, console, terminal).

---

If you only need to record a *single script call's* output in a file *while also printing it to the host*, you can use the [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Tee-Object) cmdlet:

- However - as any command in a PowerShell pipeline - `Tee-Object` only acts on data received via the *success* output stream.
- In order to pass output from *all* output streams through the pipeline, the following [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) is needed (`*` is a placeholder for *all* streams, `&` indicates the target stream of the redirection (`>`), and `1` targets the *success* output stream):

  - `*>&1`

Therefore, you were probably looking for the following:

```
./somescript.ps1 *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath out.txt
```

---

A note on capturing *colored* output:

- Both methods discussed above do *not* preserve the usual coloring you'd see in the console, such as error messages appearing in red, warnings in yellow, use of [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) with `-ForegroundColor`, ...
- The only way to capture colored output is to output *strings with embedded VT/ANSI escape sequences*.

  - E.g., outputting the following string would both print the word `green` in green as well as capture it in a file as such (with the ANSI/VT escape sequences preserved, which requires a *terminal* to render them:

    ```
    # Note: In PowerShell 7+ you can replace "$([char]27)" with "`e" 
    # or use $PSStyle - see below.
    "The next word is $([char]27)[32mgreen$([char]27)[m. The rest not."
    ```
  - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), `` `e `` is available as an escape sequence for the ESC character, as a convenient alternative to `$([char]27)`. Moreover, the [automatic `$PSStyle` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psstyle) allows allows you to express the obscure ANSI/VT sequences using *symbolic names*, e.g.:

    ```
     "The next word is $($PSStyle.Foreground.Green)green$($PSStyle.Reset). The rest not."
    ```

    - See also: [about_ANSI_Terminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ANSI_Terminals).